# Breaking R code to the next line for file paths

Tags: r

Why this works:

```
PC<-read.csv('./public-transportation/san-francisco/passenger-count.csv', header=TRUE)
```

But the following doesn't work in R:

```
inputFile <-paste('./public-transportation/',
'san-francisco/passenger-count.csv')
PC<-read.csv(inputFile, header=TRUE)
```

All I am doing is passing a variable that holds the filename? 
Sorry, I am relatively new to R. This is kinda baffling me a bit. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work because the default separator in `paste` is a space.  So you need to set `sep=""`, use `paste0`, or use `file.path`.

```
# paste with sep=""
inputFile <- paste('./public-transportation/',
  'san-francisco/passenger-count.csv', sep="")
# paste0
inputFile <- paste0('./public-transportation/',
  'san-francisco/passenger-count.csv')
# file.path
inputFile <- file.path('./public-transportation/',
  'san-francisco/passenger-count.csv')
```

Comment: Awesome!! thank you very much for the clear explanation. May your day be productive and fruitful!! :)

Comment: @oostopitre: Good to know that your question was answered. If you could tick it as "answered" then that would be appreciated by all.